# View Elements and Sources at the same time in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, devtools

I found multiple questions about seeing Sources and console at the same time and it easy to do so. When I am debugging JS it is extremely useful to explore Elements to look at the HTML structure and check the selectors while executing step by step execution.

Is there any way to vertically split the DevTool and look at Elements and Sources at the same time?
If this is not possible it could be that I am proceeding in the wrong way. How do you usually debug your JS and check the selectors within Chrome?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can reposition different tab according to your wish. You can right-click on the Sources tab and then move it to bottom.

[image: Elements and Sources tabs]

When you have the developer tools open in Chrome , go to Sources tab and then press **Esc** button. It launches console window at the bottom. [image: Console]

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to vertically split the DevTool and look at Elements and Sources at the same time?

No, not at the moment.

> How do you usually debug your JS and check the selectors within Chrome?

When you mark an element in the "Elements" tab it will be available in the console as `$0`, you can also right-click it and select "save as global variable". If you want to check CSS selectors you can "copy CSS selector" from that same menu.

You can just "switch tabs" from "sources" to "elements" to switch between the debugger and the elements tab and you can do this with a keyboard shortcut (command + shift + p to quickly switch between tabs or run actions).

You can also set DOM breakpoints (for events or when elements get changed), or use the DOM API to work with elements directly from `sources` using the console drawer.

Comment: Side note for completeness: You _can_ manually open multiple instances of the devtools and attach them to the same target (in modern chrome) - the debugger protocol supports this but it's clunky and I'm not aware of anyone who does this. Basically you'd launch chrome with the `--remote-debugging` flag, go to `chrome:inspect` and find your tab and attach to it (or do so with something like vscode's chrome debugging extension).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Switching tabs is what I am doing right now but its time consuming especially because I often lose track of wat I was looking at. I am wondering why not implementing the feature to see multiple tab at the same time: I mean is so complicated, there are any constraint in Chromium that prevent from developing such a feature? Thanks though!

Comment: I am happy to raise this suggestion to Benedikt who currently leads the devtools team in Google and is quite competent - though I think the feature request is simple enough that you can just go to https://crbug.com and ask for it. I don't think it's that common of a feature request and the answer to "why didn't anyone do it?" is probably "there are many worthwhile things to do and they probably didn't have time".

Comment: Thanks for the precious inputs! Appreciated

Comment: Happy to help and welcome to Stack Overflow! (I guess you've been here a while but this is the first question :])

Comment: Thanks. I always found the answer so there was no need to ask... until now :(

Comment: As of today, you can: see instructions by @ashu user below. Once you have the bottom "menu" open below, u can right click  "sources" tab and click "Move to bottom". Hope this helps.